# How to let currency unmodified with MathJax

Tags: mathjax

I am using MathJax with the following configuration:

```js
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]
  }
};
```

As you can see, there is nothing fancy.
I work really well and my inline math is correctly transformed.

My problem arise when I have sentences like `With a total of twenty $25,000 USD prizes for US contestants and ten $30,000 CAD prizes for the Canucks in Phase 1 of the challenge`.
As expected, the `$25,000 USD prizes for US contestants and ten $` part is interpreted by MathJax.
As you can imagine, it's not something I am looking for.

Knowing that I have no control on the content because it's inside a feed reader, is there some configuration I can use to escape that kind of strings or I am out of luck and there is nothing I can do?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/delimiters.html#tex-and-latex-math-delimiters):

> You can use \$ to prevent a dollar sign from being treated as a math delimiter within the text of your web page, e.g., use “… the cost is $2.50 for the first one, and $2.00 for each additional one …” to prevent these dollar signs from being used as math delimiters in a web page where dollar signs have been configured to be in-line delimiters.

An alternative method is to wrap $ in a span tag (since MathJax will stop searching for closing $ at the end of a span).

Comment: So basically, I am screwed since I have no control of the content :/

Comment: If you can neither change what delimiters are used nor what the content looks like, then you're on your own in figuring out workarounds. E.g., if no page has both TeX and Dollar currency, then make MathJax an opt-in for pages that need it; or you could try to adjust MathJax's script for detecting TeX to your needs and compile your own copy.